# Calculate the composite functions $f \circ g$ and $ g \circ f$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

$f(x)=3^3, \qquad g(x)=x^3$

$f(g(x))= ~?$

-for this one I got an answer of $ 3^x (x^3)$ and it was dubbed incorrect

$g(f(x))= ~?$

-for this one I got $x^3(3^x)$ and it was also incorrect. I'm not sure of what I need to do to find the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f(g(x)) = f(x^3) = 3^3$$
and
$$g(f(x)) = g(3^3)  = (3^3)^3 = 3^9$$

Comment: I'm still confused on how you achieved these answers and as I am checking them with my online hw it says the answers are incorrect.